# Checking for node-add mode in page.tpl.php

Tags: drupal

In my `page.tpl.php` I have an `‘if’` statement that checks to see what node is being used and then add a class to the `‘container’` element relative to the node i.e.

```
<div id="container" class="clear-block <?php if ($node->type == 'card'): ?>card-node-type<?php endif ?>">
```

But I would also like to add a class to the `‘container’` element in the `page.tpl.php` if I’m adding a new node `‘/node/add/card’` but I don’t know how to test for it as it is not a node type. How would I go around testing for this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution would be to check the [`args`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/arg/6) in the preprocess_page function and then add a variable you can print. You could make that dynamic to work for any node type.

Comment: Deleted my post, I think you must have got in there first with the same answer.

Comment: Thanks googletorp. There seems to be many ways to achieve the same thing with Drupal and as I'm a newbie I find it a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted it. I duplicated the `page.tpl.php` and renamed it to `page-node-add-card.tpl`.php (card being the node type I'm adding) and then added the class to the element in that file.

Comment: This is ok, but doesn't scale very well as you can quickly get lots of nearly identical templates

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I'll use the preprocess_page function as you and googletorp suggested is the correct way.